# PIC24 Reset Issue

Tags: pic, reset, mplab

I am working with the [PIC24FV16KM202](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33030a.pdf).

I am encountering resets while implementing [Dispatch](https://github.com/slightlynybbled/Dispatch), which is a serial protocol that I'm working on that grew out of a project.

The [example](https://github.com/slightlynybbled/Dispatch/tree/master/examples) that I'm working on is a function that executes when an endpoint has been sent data.  I'm using a Python script to send that piece of data through the UART to the uC.  When that data is received, `mySubscriberFunction` is executed.

```
void mySubscriberFunction(void){
    static uint16_t i = 0;

    i++;

    /* publish i back to the sender to 'close the loop' */
    DIS_publish("i,u16", &i);
}
```

As you can see, `mySubscriberFunction` is pretty simple.  It increments a counter and publishes the data back to any other subscribers.  My Python script is receiving this data and displaying it in the console.

My problem is that after i is ~998 (it has happened somewhat higher and lower, but usually 998), it simply resets.  When I'm running in debug mode, the debugger stops executing.  When I'm running in production mode, `i` simply resets to 1 and continues counting.

Another thing that is odd is that, during debugging, I have paused the debugger.  If I pause the debugger at i=100, then the reset occurs at ~1098 instead of ~998.  If I pause at i=200, then the reset occurs at ~1198 instead of ~998, and so on.

The usual suspects for this sort of reset are attempting to execute an interrupt that doesn't have an interrupt vector, overwriting the PC and/or stack with garbage, or other fun and difficult-to-debug problems like that.  I was just hoping that someone out there might have experienced a similar problem and could point me in the correct direction.

Dispatch isn't a large project, so it is plausible to look through the code to spot the problem, but I suspect that the debugger symptom will point someone in the correct direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake.  I found another facet of the symptom, that it was time related and not `i` related.  This is usually a dead giveway that the Watchdog Timer is resetting the device.

I had copied the 'config.h' file from another project in which I was using the WDT; however, I didn't clear the WDT in this project.

The solution: Turn off the watchdog timer or clear the watchdog timer.

Thank you for your patience,